# How to read data from Azure Mobile app in C# UWP

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a really simple login system and a table to put few names in C#.

the code that I use to connect to the Azure Mobile APP is this:

```
IMobileServiceTable<Users> UsernameTBObj = App.MobileService.GetTable<Users>();
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Users obj = new Users();
        obj.Username = txtUsername.Text;
        obj.Password = txtPassword.Password.ToString();

        UsernameTBObj.InsertAsync(obj);
    }catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

The code for Users is this:

```
class Users
{
    public int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

with this, I can add data to the table, but I cant understand how to retrieve them. I just want to know the basics of how to do it, good security doesnt matter.  I just want to know how to make a retrieving connection string for a table and login system.

Saw many videos on youtube but nothing which would work for me. So, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check out the book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - particularly chapter 3.

The table reference can be used with LINQ.  Check out the [official HOWTO docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library) for details.

Finally, chapter 2 of my book covers authentication, including username/password auth.